# JQuery dialog only shows up after JS processing

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog

I have the following code:

[DOCUMENT READY]

```
$("#hincl_working").dialog({autoOpen: false, modal: true});
```

[SOME JS FUNCTION]

```
$("#hincl_working").dialog("open");
```

PROCESSING (takes a few seconds sometimes)

I would like the dialog to open BEFORE the processing starts (and then close right after the processing), but the dialog only shows up AFTER the processing, which is not what I want.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use javascript's setTimeout to delay your processing with 100 milliseconds or so

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

call your PROCESSING function like this, maybe also change the casing.

```
window.setTimeout(function(){PROCESSING(tile, id)}, 100);
```

Comment: I tried adding the following:
var timeID = window.setTimeout(PROCESSING ( tile, id ), 1000 );
but it doesn't work (the dialog no longer shows up at all)

Comment: You an probably even lower the timeout to 100 or 50 or so, just to make sure it doesn't seem unresponsive.

Comment: I thought as much. It works fine with the timeout set to 50. Thanx